# Drupal 7 - RewriteRule in htaccess file with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, drupal-7

i have a question about writing a rule in the htaccess file which is located in the root directory of drupal. We use the Drupal 7 version.

We want to write a rule for the url that when i go to the page "/newpage/1/name" it should target the "/oldpage?id=1&user=name". So the targetpage is a page which is created in drupal itself (a added content from a contenttype).

But i always get the same "Page not found"-Error. I can access the "/oldpage" by the way

I tried some rules about simply rewriteUrl without any parameters (to make a start). But it also didn't work for me. Here my try:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage /newpage [L,R=301]
```

This line is below this part:

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So are there any special rules for writing rules in the htaccess file in drupal? (maybe especially in version 7) or what is wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0):

Reading this site [Guide](https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide) ,I would try the following line

```
RewriteRule oldpage?id=(.*)&user=(.*)/$ /newpage/$1/$2
```